# How to create suspended process from c# without P/Invoke?

Tags: c#, process, pinvoke, createprocess, suspend

WinAPI CreateProcess has the flag CREATE_SUSPENDED so it's possible to attach process to JobObject before it has done something and then to call ResumeThread for its main thread. The only that I found searching for a solution is [this post](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/suspended-process-creation-c-app-t1349419.html) written 11 years ago!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to do this is with `CreateProcess`. The .net `Process` class does not offer the functionality. Either p/invoke `CreateProcess` or use a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly to call the same.

Comment: Does C++/CLI has more interoperability with WinAPI? May be it's worth to create a "proxy" assembly in C++ for using from C#.

Comment: A mixed mode C++/CLI assembly can include the windows headers, and link directly to unmanaged libraries. All can be done with pinvoke just easier with C++/CLI.